# Java 8 toMap for a Map<string, Collection<String>>

Tags: java, collections, filter, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8 and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to get this data into a map -

I'm reading out data from a configuration file - and it looks something like this (example) -

```
SomeName = {
   someAttribute = "attributeVal",
   someImportantAttributeList = ("val1", "val2", "val3"),
   ...
}

SomeName2 = {
   someAttribute ....
} 

...
```

I'm trying to collect the data into a map, so that the map is a Map w/ the Key being SomeName and the Value being a Collection of Strings (the "someImportantAttributeList".)

All the other data doesn't matter.

Right now I have something like this:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> mapping = configReader.getConfig()
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().containsKey("someImportantAttributeList")
    . ????
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly get this to map into a String, Collection map?

The stream itself would appear to be of entries whose values are Key = SomeName, value = an inner map of String / Object type. (so in this case, the entry's key would be SomeName, the value would be another mapping of String key (someAttribute) and Object value (the value of that attribute).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: from [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/909/creating-a-frequency-map#t=2016072817494356061)

Answer (score 2):

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, entry -> 
 (Collection<String>) entry.getValue().get("someImportantAttributeList")));
```